AGP 8.0 .so is not an ABI for 3rd party library
Upgrading from AGP 7.4.2 to 8.x causes a previously working android project to produce the compile error:
filename extracted from path /home/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/16c9c480f14ca901b62b3ace2fbca16c/transformed/filename/armeabi-v9a/libfile.so is not an ABI

I have read the associated bug on the bugtracker, and also the other SO question.  Both threads focus on building your own library and workarounds for that case, but they do not apply to my case:
I have a 3rd party provided .jar file with native libraries and class files.  The structure of the .jar file is lib/<arch>/<lib>.so and the class files are included with the namespace starting at the root.
It compiles and works fine in 7.4.2, but when upgrading to 8.+, I get the error.
It looks like gradle extracts the .jar file to its cache without the lib folder, but the toAbiRootedPath still assumes it's there (so it grabs the wrong parent folder?).
If I modify the .jar file to eliminate the lib folder, so that the file structure is <arch>/<lib>.so, then it gets past the check in toAbiRootedPath with no error, but at runtime Android is unable to find the .so files and I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError.
I'm not really sure what else to try.

can't you follow my comment and see if it worked ?

So it turns out the error message is a complete red herring.  It is actually looking at the correct part of the directory, it just turns out that the <arch> included in the .jar is invalid.
The ABIs that get checked against are (looking up the source):
public static final String ABI_ARMEABI = "armeabi"
public static final String ABI_ARMEABI_V7A = "armeabi-v7a"
public static final String ABI_ARM64_V8A = "arm64-v8a"; 
public static final String ABI_INTEL_ATOM = "x86";
public static final String ABI_INTEL_ATOM64 = "x86_64";
public static final String ABI_MIPS = "mips"; 
public static final String ABI_MIPS64 = "mips64";

If any of the directories in lib/ don't match one of these, it produces the compiler error.
